# Does deltalake-rs support streaming?

Tags: delta-lake

Does anyone knows if it is possible to use deltalake-rs for streaming with datafusion in Rust? I can’t seem to find anything on this.

Spark does have it. See https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#delta-table-as-a-sink I am looking at reproducing at least the reading of the stream part using datafusion.